# firebase cloud function transaction Cannot set property

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

i have a cloud firebase function. I want to match users here. but when I want to update the new user list in transaction. Everything works fine until I get to the transaction. it just gives a problem in the update process I get an error. where did i go wrong?

```
 function EslesmeUser(userID, gameID, users, level) {
      this.userID = userID;
      this.gameID = gameID;
      this.users = users;
      this.level = level;
    }
    
    
exports.miniOyunEslemeOnline = functions.database.ref("/test/guncelle22/{player}")
.onCreate((eslesecekSnap, context) => {
  return database.ref().child("test").child("guncelle22").once("value").then((players) => {

    const eslesecek = new EslesmeUser(eslesecekSnap.key, eslesecekSnap.child("gameID").val(), eslesecekSnap.child("users").val(), eslesecekSnap.child("level").val());
    eslesecek.users[0] = "testuser1";

    database.ref().child("test").child("guncelle22").transaction(function (players) {    
        const NewValue = {
          gameID: eslesecek.gameID,
          level: eslesecek.level,   
          users: eslesecek.users,
        };
        players[eslesecek.userID] = NewValue; //---> ERROR İS HERE.
      return players;
    });

    return null;
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
});
```

error screen shot ( eslesecek.userID = usersid000)

[image: error]

my db model

[image: db model]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time it runs, your transaction handler will be called with `null`. Even if you *know* a value exists in the database, you'll need to deal with this null, and return what the data *should* become if no data exists.

So something like this:

```
database.ref().child("test").child("guncelle22").transaction(function (players) {
    if (players !== null) {
        const NewValue = {
          gameID: eslesecek.gameID,
          level: eslesecek.level,   
          users: eslesecek.users,
        };
        players[eslesecek.userID] = NewValue;
    }
    return players;
});
```

With the updated code:

1. The first time your callback is run, it will get `null` and returns `null` to the database too.
2. The database then notices that the data is actually not `null`, and your code executes again, but now with the correct value for `players`.